# Redirecting pipeline output in bash

Tags: bash

running this command in bash

```
echo hello | > ./out
```

File `./out` is empty and nothing gets printed.

So I wonder, what is actually happening here? I would expect this is an error.

Thanks,
Fous

Comment: There is only `|&`, `>|` in the documentation...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I usually see somthing like `echo hello > out`.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited, to "practical, answerable" questions. Defining behavior for code nobody would ever intentionally write is not practical, particularly when that behavior is undefined and subject to change without notice; the only correct answer for undefined behavior is "don't write code that does that".

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to :

`echo | true`

To summarize, pipe output is connected to a subshell, but as redirection operators like `>` are the firsts to be executed by the shell, and as there is no initial input to this subshell, you'll get an empty a.out.

Even `echo xxx | > a.out` will give you an empty a.out file.

To be more clear, `> a.out` at the right side of the pipe implies a subshell. This subshell will first execute the redirection operator before processing any pipe input.

Thus, the title of your question is wrong, you are not redirecting any pipeline output here with this command. You are only redirecting the output of the subshell invoked in the right side of a pipeline.

Comment: I'm not sure it's accurate to say that the `> a.out` implies a subshell, even when caveated w/ being dependent on the pipe -- having _any_ command on the right-hand side of a pipe implies a subshell, even without a redirection at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've started with "This is equivalent to `echo | true` but i wasn't sure it would be understandable for OP. It is mainly to mean to OP that the right side with redirection will imply a subshell in every case. Do you think i should revert to "equivalent to `echo | true`" (or false if redirection fails) ?

Comment: I do think that the way you first described it is less prone to being understood incorrectly. (It might not be understood at all, but I'd argue that that's better than thinking one understands but actually having it wrong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see your point, i'll edit the answer.